# Strange error when issuing a SELECT statement on a remote database on a program

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado, remote-server

I am making a program that reads, inserts, and updates data from a remote database. I have tested out the program through my local host and it works perfectly. I am having problems, however, when I replicate the same procedures on a remote database from GoDaddy. I want to get the minimum and maximum recorded dates from orders and the following error occurs:

[image: Image with strange error]

When I check for the value of maxdate all the debugger shows is "{Length: 10}". I have run the same statement through HeidiSQL on the same database the result is as expected:

[image: HeidiSQL doesn't give me this error]

Can you please tell me what is going on? I am thinking that since I am querying from a remote database it doesn't have enough time to give me the desired results. Thank you!

Comment: Uhm what is the ToString method do, i guess rs().Value already is a String type?

Comment: @PSo apologies for the confusion. I added the "toString" to see if it made a difference but forgot yo remove it.

Comment: so now, the problem is you can read rs("min") but u cannot read rs("max")?

Comment: Check the variable type of maxdate? and the loop condition seems weird?

Comment: @PSo, I don't know if rs("min") can be read since it also has the if statement inside it. I added the loop to see if my hunch was correct and the program needed a little more time to get the value.

Comment: Also, I noticed that there was more on the "{Length = 10}" inside the rs("min"). There are 10 different numbers whose origin I don't know.